# LARAVEL 5: Need to keep query string after auth redirects

Tags: authentication, redirect, laravel-5

I have a link I am sending via email. For example, www.swings.com/worker?id=3382&tok=jfli3uf

In this case I want the person to click the link, get sent to the login page(which it does) and then be directed to a controller method WITH the $id and $tok variables. I can't get that part to work. Any ideas? I am only using the RedirectIfAuthenticated class and this is what it looks like:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = $request->user();
    if ($this->auth->check()) {
        if($user && $user->hasRole('worker'))
        {
            return redirect('worker');
        }
        return redirect('home');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

hasRole is a method I created in the User model that checks the role of the logged in user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFTER SOME HOURS I WAS ABLE TO HAVE A SOLUTION:

ReturnIfAuthenticated wasn't changed. I just added the following within my controller that this link should go to:

for instance, the route would be:

```
Route::get('worker', 'WorkerController@methodINeed');
```

Within this method:

```
public function methodINeed() {
    $id = Input::get('id');
    $tok = Input::get('tok');
// Do what I need this variables to do
}
```

What I didn't understand and what could not be properly understood is that the auth controller in Laravel 5 is triggered when a user is a guest it will still redirect to the actual method with all its original data once auth is successful. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can flash data to the session when redirecting by chaining the with() method:

```
// in your handle() method:
return redirect('home')->with($request->only('id', 'tok'));

// then in home controller method:

$id = session('id');
$tok = session('tok');
```

Comment: This didn't work. Its returning null. Is there another way? I don't want anything else then when the user clicks the link he logs in and proceed on his marry way to the actual page related to the link. Why does it clear everything. I have the route set for the link so if they were already logged in it would work